# Leap year program doesn't seem to run

Tags: c++, date, if-statement, statements

Question -  A year with 366 days is called a leap year. A year is a leap year if it is divisible by four (for example, 1980), except that it is not a leap year if it is divisible by 100 (for example, 1900); however, it is a leap year if it is divisible by 400 (for example, 2000). There were no exceptions before the introduction of the Gregorian calendar on October 15, 1582.  Write a program that asks the user for a year and computes whether that year is a leap year.

**This is what I have so far, and the program doesn't seem to run for years greater than 1582. Could someone help me out why? Thanks a bunch**

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
cout<< "Pleas enter a year: " <<endl;
int year = 0;
cin >> year;

if (year <= 1581)
{
    if (year % 4 == 0)
    {
        cout << "It's a leap year, wow! " << endl;
    }

    else 
    {
        cout << "It's not a leap year " << endl;

    }
}

else if (year > 1581)
{
    if (year % 4 == 0)
    {
        if (year % 100 == 0)
        {
            cout<< "It is not a leap year " << endl;
        }
        else if (year % 400 == 0)
        {
            cout<< "It is a leap year, Wow!" << endl;
        }
    }

}

else
{
    cout<< "You entered a wrong year number "<< year<<  endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: C++? Tag as such, if it is.

Comment: What would I need to enter to get to the last `else`?

Answer (score 1):

You are making it very complex. I don't think you need to care about whether the year is greater than 1582 or not (for a 4 digit number) provided that a leap year is one which is:

• Divisible by 400
  **OR**
• NOT divisible by 100 **AND** divisible by 4.
Using unnecessary nested ifs can make your code long and error prone. Try this method:

```
#include<iostream.h>
int main(){
    int y=0;
    cout << "Enter a year\n";
    cin >> y;
    cout <<"\n"<<y;
    if(y%400==0 || (y%100!=0 && y%4==0))
    cout <<" is a leap year";
    else
    cout <<" is not a leap year";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without check if year > 1582

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int year;
    cout<< "Please enter a year: " <<endl;
    cin >> year;

    if( year%25 && !(year&3) || !(year&15) )
        cout << "It's a leap year!" << endl;
    else
        cout << "It's not a leap year!" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a number of cases in the handling of years after 1581.

- printing "Not leap year" unless (year % 4 == 0)
- The third case where a year divisible by 4 is neither divisible by 100 nor 400

It as simple as you have just not written any code that is run when year is 2004, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing 2 else statement

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
cout<< "Pleas enter a year: " <<endl;
int year = 0;
cin >> year;

if (year <= 1581)
{
    if (year % 4 == 0)
    {
        cout << "It's a leap year, wow! " << endl;
    }

    else 
    {
        cout << "It's not a leap year " << endl;

    }
}

else if (year > 1581)
{
    if (year % 4 == 0)
    {
        if (year % 100 == 0)
        {
            cout<< "It is not a leap year " << endl;
        }
        else if (year % 400 == 0)
        {
            cout<< "It is a leap year, Wow!" << endl;
        }
        // <----------- Here you are missing an else
    }
    // <----------- Here you are missing an else
}

else
{
    cout<< "You entered a wrong year number "<< year<<  endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Walter Thanks for the constructive feedback where you clearly pointed out which error I missed.

Comment: think about what happens for year=2000.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest

```
if (    ((year % 400) == 0)
     || (   ((year % 4) == 0) // or (year & 0x3) == 0
         && (   (year <= 1581)
             || ((year % 100) != 0) )))
   cout << "It's a leap year, wow! " << endl;
else
   cout << "It's not a leap year " << endl;
```

or

```
if (    ((year % 4) == 0) // or  year & 0x3 == 0
     && (   (year <= 1581)
         || ((year % 100) != 0)
         || ((year % 400) == 0) ) )
   cout << "It's a leap year, wow! " << endl;
else
   cout << "It's not a leap year " << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

It’s a good idea to simplify your conditionals.  A general method for this is to convert to a normal form—either conjunctive or disjunctive—and put the tests that are most likely to short-circuit, first.  For simple cases such as this, you can just eyeball it.

In this case, conjuctive normal form is extremely simple:

```
year%4 == 0 &&
( year < 1582 || year%100 != 0 || year%400 == 0 )
```

That is, the year is divisible by four and any of the three conditions of the Gregorian calendar reform do not hold.  Since the first `&&` term that is false, and the first `||` term that is true, short-circuit the expression, we want to put the clauses that are most likely to short-circuit, first.

Note that you can code-golf `year%100 != 0` to `year%100` inside a conditional expression, and `year%2000 == 0` to `!(year%2000)`, if you find that easier to read.

It makes sense to move this to a helper function.  We can mark it `constexpr` to give the compiler a hint that it can calculate whether constants are leap years or not at compile-time.

I don't like to post complete answers to what look like homework problems, but that ship has sailed.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;

constexpr bool is_leap(const int year)
{
  // Conjunctive normal form:
  return ( year%4 == 0 &&
           ( year < 1582 || year%100 != 0 || year%400 == 0 ) );
}

int main()
{
  int year = 0; // Used only within the body of the loop that sets it.

  while (cin >> year)
    cout << year
         << ( is_leap(year) ? " is a leap year.\n"
                            : " is not a leap year.\n" );

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Even for a trivial program such as this, there’s a design decision worth thinking about: do we declare `int year;` uninitialized, or initialize it to a bad value such as `int year = 0;`?  In this case, it’s safe either way, because `year` is only used inside the body of the loop that sets it.  If we don’t initialize it, though, we might later refactor the code to use `year` outside the loop, and then there might be a code path where `year` is used before it’s initialized (causing undefined behavior!)  On the other hand, if we do initialize `year`, we might prevent the compiler from noticing that there’s a path where it’s used before it was initialized for real.  I personally prefer to initialize to an invalid value and `assert` that it has been updated before use.

Answer (score -1):

Or you can simply write the following program:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int year;
    cout << "Enter year: ";
    cin >> year;

    if ((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0){
        cout << "It is a leap year" << endl;
    }
    else{
        cout << "It is not a leap year" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```